# Is it ok to have a class without creating instances of it?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I have a question concerning good programming style. I have a group of methods that is handling the flow of my program. These functions uses objects from another class. Is it fine to make a class called something like `Functions` and list these functions I have there? Not a single instance would be created of this class. Should I rather not include these functions in a class at all? Basically they do stuff like opening the Main Menu and alike.

Not sure if this is a stupid question, I couldn't find any similar topics on this forum. I'm not asking how to do this, rather how to handle it regarding style.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a C++ namespace instead?

Comment: why not just put functions into a _namespace_?

Comment: That seems like a great idea - I'm new to c++ so wasn't aware this was possible :)

Comment: In sticking with OOP, I would say throw them in a class. Something like `Utils` might be a better name. Though in a class or in a namespace will probably look very similar. But, to my knowledge, a namespace should be reserved for things that belong together (sort of like a class, but bigger), so, how closely linked are these functions with the classes they use? If these classes also use them, I'd say 'no' on namespace. But I'm sure everyone will have their own opinion.

Comment: Dukeling has a point here.

Comment: Well, since these "utility" functions take objects from one of these classes as arguments, I'd say they are very related.

Comment: If I take the OOP way of doing it, I guess I'd need to make all these functions static - correct?

Comment: Yes, they'll need to be static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **exactly** what namespaces are for. Don't try to wedge things into "the OOP way" when they don't fit. If your design says that you'll never create an object of a class type then it's not a class, just an agglomeration of functions.

Comment: I'm getting very different repsonses from people with high reputations... I don't know what I should do ^^

Comment: @wizH - some people have OOP religion, and insist that everything has to be a class. Mostly that's because they come to C++ from Java and don't know any better. C++ is a multi-paradigm language: you pick your tool to fit the job. Otherwise you end up driving screws with a hammer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems as the namespace is best intended for this purpose then :)

Comment: It seems silly to define my class that handles the calculations before this "Utils" namespace. Is this the way it's supposed to be? I need to access the methods it holds from my util functions.

Answer (score 1):

While reading your question, I instantly thought about the Math class in Java (not sure what is the C++ equivalent). You probably know it, it is basically a collection of math operations. [Math class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

In my opinion, the kind of class you're talking about in your question must have a "collection of **general** functions" objective, similar to the Math class. Things like opening a menu should be a method of that menu or that menu's parent.

On the other hand, things like calculating some values using specific objects from your program or formatting elements following a customized pattern should be gathered in a "static" class in order to make that class an utilitary tool in your program.

Math operations are very **general** functions that can apply to any program. Try to transpose this concept within the context of your program! ;)

Comment: `Math` is only a class in Java because Java forces you to put everything in classes. C++ provides namespaces for grouping related things that don't logically belong in a class.

Comment: True. I'm not that familiar with namespaces in c++, but I wanted to insist on the difference between specific actions on objects (methods) and general actions using objects rather than specific application of those concepts.

Answer (score -1):

Put them in a class as static functions for now.  You may realize later you'll have some commonality... perhaps state?  Storing that in the class might make sense.  And you'll want to check things there perhaps before calling your other objects... before you know it, you'll remove your static aspects and instantiate your own object.  Perhaps even later consider multiple threads and several of these objects.  You get the idea... leave yourself room for an object-oriented approach...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had actually already done this before your comment, as Dukeling suggested the OOP way of doing it too :)

I would have to forward declare the class then, as the previous class needs to use these functions - yes?

Comment: It sounds like various answerers are speculating on what your classes and functions are doing and are coming to different conclusions.  It really depends on what your design/implementation is.  If you're calling classes from functions and functions from classes you might re-look at how you're organizing data and methods as opposed to forward declarations (wherever possible).  And yes maybe namespace does make sense for what you're doing.  And no, I don't come from Java land, but 20 years of C++ has taught me the importance of OOP in large projects =)